# How to formally prove that random guess is the best attack

Tags: provable-security

How to formally argue that there exists no efficient $A$ who can come up with a $e$ such that $$\begin{align}x&=PRF(e,0) \land \\ y &= PRF(e,1) \land \\ x &= H(y)\end{align}$$ where $H$ is a secure hash function and $|x|=|y|=\ell$?

Note that it's easy to argue that if $A$ just guesses randomly, the success probability for each guess is negligible (something like $\frac{1}{2^{\ell}}$). But how to argue there is no better algorithm than guessing?

Answer (score 2):

> But how to argue there is no better algorithm than guessing?

Show that, if there is a better algorithm than guessing, you can distinguish the PRF from random.

Comment: can you elaborate a little bit. I know the rough idea but I find it tricky to be very precise.

Comment: Maybe you can look at some reduction arguments in [the crypto book](https://toc.cryptobook.us/book.pdf).